# Sencha Touch date code works good in Chrome but fails on Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, safari, sencha-touch

I have the following code

```
var date = Ext.Date.format('2013-04-02', 'Y-n-j')
var formattedDate=Ext.Date.format('2013-04-02', 'M d')
console.log(date);
console.log(formattedDate);
```

On Chrome it correctly prints out the date on the console. In Safari it fails. Who is correct and more importantly what is the best way to handle this?

Safari throws following error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'utilDate.monthNames[month].substring')

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why it would work in Chrome, but you're missing a single quote after the second `.format(`

Comment: chrome many times ignores js minor errors, which other browsers dont, so this can be the reason.

Comment: I have typed my code here..so it is not messing in my real code.I have updated my code above.

Answer (score 1):

Safari is silently not known for this bug, seen on ipad : not handling such a native Date creation `new Date("2013-04-02")`.

This may be the issue and there you will have to do the splitting work before and so provide directly the Date object : `new Date(2013, 3, 2)` instead of your date string.

That fully explains your issue : a not parsed Date answers no month with getMonth, thus there is no monthName for this month that is not a month and thus substring fails when called from something that doesn't have this method since it's not a string.